# How can I disable Websphere's 8.5 default 4xx message?

Tags: http-status-code-404, jersey-2.0, websphere-8

I have a Jersey REST application in Websphere 8.5. Whenever my resource responds with a 4xx response, Webpshere (or IBM Http Server) overwrites the response body with its default error message, for example:

> Error 404: Not Found

Not only don't I want the response body to be overwritten, I want the response body as produced by my resource, but also Websphere does not update the `Content-Length:` response header, thereby creating an inconsistency between content-length and the actual response body length.

Is there a way to force Websphere (or IBM HTTP server) to **not** overwrite the response body when my resource produces a 4xx response?

For example a call to the following resource:

```
@Path("timeout")
public class TimeoutService {
    @GET
    @Path("withbody")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getWithBody() {
        Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);

        builder.entity("{ \"status\" : \"notok\" }");
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

will result in:

```
Error 404: No

Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
Response Headers
$WSEP:
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Length:13
Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Tue,21 Apr 2015 11:50:38 GMT>
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.0
```

Note how the default message gets truncated because of the inconsistent content length.

But what I want is this call to respond with a `404` and `{ "status" : "notok" }` and `Content-Type` set to `application/json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Here is the page that outlines the Jersey property that needs to be changed to disable WAS hi-jacking your errors:

```
https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2521
```

In short, you have to set the property `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR` to `true` when you configure Jersey.

Comment: Thanks for this, this problem has caused me hours of pain and your answer likely saved me from hours more.